# undefined columns selected problem when trying to run this code

Tags: r

I am trying to use the air dataset from the `dummies` package.

I tried:

```
library(dummies)
dumair<-air[c(5:18)]
```

but that throws the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(air, c(5:18)) : undefined columns selected
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which columns you want to select. When selecting rows and columns from a dataframe, you need to specify them like this:

```
df[rows, columns]
```

If you need all columns, leave the "columns" field empty. Same if you want all rows but only some columns!

I believe you want to select all columns, but only the rows from 5 to 18, right?

So doing:

```
dumair <- air[c(5:18), ]
```

Should work!

Comment: It worked, thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad to help! Can you mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: yes yes done that, thanks yaa :-D it was creating an issue for my assignment